# Can .htaccess take over directory traversal?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible for .htaccess to take over directory traversal?

Given existing endpoint: www.mysite.com/my-app/index.php
User requested endpoint: www.mysite.com/my-app/users/list

- I would like the directory traversal to be haulted once it reaches "~/my-app" and all requests directed to "~/my-app/index.php".
- I would like the url they entered not to be altered.
- I would like "~/my-app/index.php" to know the originally requested url so it can make logical decisions based upon it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean just something like this?

In the htaccess file in your "my-app" directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Or you can just forget the `?url=$1` part and have your index.php script look in server variables like: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you very much!  I'm brand new to the RewriteEngine and I didn't really see anything that I thought would not change the url in this manner.  Very much appreciated!